# mapPanel topToolbar functions doesn't works

Tags: extjs

I use geoExt with ExtJs3.4 in my application!.I create a mapPanel and add openlayers map into it with below code.

```
var mapPanel = new GeoExt.MapPanel({
        renderTo: 'gxmap',
        height: 500,
        width: 800,
        map: map,
        title: 'Map'
    });
```

after that i create extjs toggle button

```
var button = new Ext.Button({
text: 'Measure Things',
enableToggle: true,
handler: function(toggled){
    if (toggled) {
        polygon.activate();
    } else {
        polygon.deactivate();
    }
}
});
```

when i want to add this button to map panel i get topPanel of mapPanel and after that when i want to use topPanel functions these functions doesn't works!

```
mapPanel.getTopToolbar().addButton(button);
```

or below code

```
topToolbar = mapPanel.getTopToolbar();
topToolbar.addButton(button);
```

when i see chrome developer tool i see this error for addButton function or other functions of topToolbar of panel!
**error:**

```
uncaught typeError: cannot call method 'addButton' of undefined
```

why i can't use topToolbar functions?
Link for tutorial of geoext that use `mapPanel.getTToolbar().addButton(button);`
[Adding Buttons to map](http://geoext.org/tutorials/control-button-tutorial.html#extjs-buttons)

Comment: you mean apPanel.getTopToolbar().addButton(button) ?

Comment: Yes i can't use addButton to add buttons to panel or using other methods

Comment: I'm not familliar with geoExt, but it extends Ext.panel where it gets the method getTopToolbar(), So your error sais that the toptoolbar is undefined ... do you have a tot toolbar on your toolbar?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. You have to add this extra line before the mapPanel creation:

```
var toolbar = new Ext.Toolbar();
```

And inside the mapPanel add this property:

```
tbar: toolbar
```

You can add now your button to the toolbar:

```
mapPanel.getTopToolbar().addButton(button);
```